# Splitting Address in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to be able to split an address in SQL Server . I have a sample address

```
(10396 Whispering Pines Dr Frisco TX 75033-3807)
```

The street name might have multiple names but the zip code is always at the end and the state is next to it and then the city, etc...

I was thinking I would start by cutting off the zip+4 and then work backwards (get the zip and remove it. Then get the state (always 2 digits) and remove it and then the city.

Everything else will be the street address. The address I have included above is how it is stored in the database. I tried doing this myself but I know there has to be a better way!

```
declare @streetAddress varchar(1500)
declare @zip varchar(10)
declare @state varchar(2)
declare @city varchar(250)

set @streetAddress = '10396 Whispering Pines Dr Frisco TX 75033-3807'

SET @streetAddress =  left(@streetAddress,charindex('-',@streetAddress) - 1)
SET @zip = right(@streetAddress,5)
SET @streetAddress = RTRIM(replace(@streetAddress,right(@streetAddress,5),''))
SET @state = right(@streetAddress,2)
SET @streetAddress = rtrim(replace(@streetAddress,right(@streetAddress,2),''))
SET @city = reverse(LEFT(reverse(@streetAddress),charindex(' ',@streetAddress)))
select @streetAddress,@state,@zip,@city
```

The output looks like this:

```
|10396 Whispering Pines Dr|TX|75033|Frisco|
```

Comment: I doubt it's possible, what if the city consists of two words like `New York`?`

Comment: I have done this sort of thing using SSIS. You need reference tables of state codes and city names. However you may need to allow for misspellings etc.

Comment: Hi Travis, I just edited my answer and added a completely different approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(100)='10396 Whispering Pines Dr Frisco TX 75033-3807';
DECLARE @testRev VARCHAR(100)=REVERSE(@test);
DECLARE @pos1 INT=CHARINDEX(' ',@testRev);
DECLARE @pos2 INT=CHARINDEX(' ',@testRev,@pos1+1);
DECLARE @pos3 INT=CHARINDEX(' ',@testRev,@pos2+1); 

DECLARE @part4 VARCHAR(100)=REVERSE(LEFT(@testRev,@pos1-1));
DECLARE @part3 VARCHAR(100)=REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@testRev,@pos1+1,@pos2-@pos1));
DECLARE @part2 VARCHAR(100)=REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@testRev,@pos2+1,@pos3-@pos2));
DECLARE @part1 VARCHAR(100)= REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@testRev,@pos3,1000));

SELECT @part1, @part3,@part4,@part2
```

The result

```
10396 Whispering Pines Dr    TX     75033-3807   Frisco
```

### EDIT: another approach

The advantage of this approach was, to get all parts (separated by blanks) in one go. This would make it easier to continue wiht any logic to solve the *multi-word* problem...

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(100)='10396 Whispering Pines Dr Frisco TX 75033-3807';
DECLARE @testRev VARCHAR(100)=REVERSE(@test);

DECLARE @casted XML=(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@testRev,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML));

SELECT REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')) AS ZIP
      ,REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')) AS State
      ,REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')) AS City
      ,ISNULL(REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')) + ' ','')
      +ISNULL(REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')) + ' ','')    
      +ISNULL(REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')) + ' ','')
      +ISNULL(REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')) + ' ','')    
      +ISNULL(REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')) + ' ','')    
      +ISNULL(REVERSE(@casted.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')) + ' ','') AS TheRest
```

Comment: Oh, I was to fast, just saw, that you'd need the city separated. In this case HoneyBadgers comment is very true: How should an algorithm know how to split a multi-word-city and a multi-word street...

Comment: Hi, to get closer to your example, I just added the splitting of the city. But the issue of multi-word-cities is still an open question...

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the acceptance check. I already up voted but I forgot about the check mark. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's going to be virtually impossible to workout if the city has a space in the name, here's a suggestion based on a lookup table and some reference data from http://www.geonames.org (I can't vouch for completeness of this source)

```
CREATE TABLE PostReference
    (
     CountryCode CHAR(2)
    ,PostalCode CHAR(5)
    ,PlaceName VARCHAR(180)
    ,AdminName1 VARCHAR(100)
    ,AdminCode1 VARCHAR(20)
    ,AdminName2 VARCHAR(100)
    ,AdminCode2 VARCHAR(20)
    ,AdminName3 VARCHAR(100)
    ,AdminCode3 VARCHAR(20)
    ,Latitude DECIMAL(7, 4)
    ,Longitude DECIMAL(7, 4)
    ,Accuracy CHAR(1)
    );
GO

BULK INSERT PostReference
FROM 'D:\US\US.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a');
GO
```

Then a (less than optimal) query - I'm sure you can improve on this.

```
DECLARE @Address VARCHAR(100) = '10396 Whispering Pines Dr Frisco TX 75033-3807'
SELECT 
    LEFT(@Address, CHARINDEX(PlaceName, @Address) - 1) StreetAddress
    ,PlaceName
    ,AdminCode1 State
    ,RIGHT(@Address, LEN(@Address) - CHARINDEX(PostalCode, @Address) + 1) ZipCode
FROM PostReference
WHERE @Address LIKE '%' + PlaceName + ' ' + AdminCode1 + ' ' + PostalCode+'%'


StreetAddress                        PlaceName       State  ZipCode
------------------------------------ --------------- ------ -----------
10396 Whispering Pines Dr            Frisco          TX     75033-3807

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Hope this is of use.